# SQL Find Brand New Clients

Tags: sql, min

I am trying to run a script to pull only clients where their first ever (min) invoice date was yesterday.  A stored proc is going to run to deliver the results on Friday mornings (we run our billing on Thursdays), so it would return any new clients based upon that first invoice date of yesterday.

Dbo.invoice contains our invoices;

dbo.company contains the client records;

dbo.contact contains the actual client employees;

dbo.match contains the product/service being sold

```
select 
co.company_id, co.name, i.DATE_EFFECTIVE, i.INVOICE_ID
from dbo.match m
    inner join dbo.contact c on m.CONTACT_ID_BILLING = c.CONTACT_ID
    inner join dbo.company co on c.COMPANY_ID = co.COMPANY_ID
    inner join dbo.invoice i on co.company_id = i.company_id
WHERE min(i.date_effective) = (getdate() - 1)
```

^^^ something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select co.company_id, co.name, min(i.DATE_EFFECTIVE)
from dbo.match m join
     dbo.contact c
     on m.CONTACT_ID_BILLING = c.CONTACT_ID join
     dbo.company co
     on c.COMPANY_ID = co.COMPANY_ID join
     dbo.invoice i
      on co.company_id = i.company_id
group by co.company_id, co.name
having min(i.data_effective) >= dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and
       min(i.data_effective) < convert(date, getdate());
```

This does not include the invoice id.  It does not seem particularly important in this context.  If there is only one, then you can add `max(i.invoice_id)` to the `select`.

Comment: Hmm, looks like that didn't work.  I can confirm that there are three company IDs that have a first invoice of 5/7/2020, but that returned 0 results.  Any ideas?

Comment: @burghman217 . . . I fixed the logic.  If it still doesn't work, hardcode the date '2020-05-07' in the query -- it should work.  If you see the companies with the hardcoded date, then the issue might be `getdate()` is in a different timezone.